# How do I convert FRAME's AccountId to network specific SS58?

Tags: substrate

I want to convert `AccountId` to `SS58` format with a custom network prefix.

Basically replicate the following from [JS utilities](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate-js-utilities/), e.g.:

**Change Address Prefix (Prefix Lookup), Prefix = 50**

`5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY`

`65ADzWZUAKXQGZVhQ7ebqRdqEzMEftKytB8a7rknW82EASXB`

How to do it generically in a Substrate pallet? Do I need to add an associated type into my configuration trait extending the `Ss58Codec` trait or can I somehow convert `AccountId` to `AccountId32` and then use its `to_ss58check_with_version()` function?

Comment: It does not make sense to look at SS58 inside of a Substrate pallet. You should only use AccountId. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Similarly to the [Claims](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/common/src/claims.rs) pallet, I want to construct an Ethereum message but instead of hex representation of an account I want user to sign a message with their SS58 address. So instead of `I claim to wallet:d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d` I want the message to be `I claim to wallet:65ADzWZUAKXQGZVhQ7ebqRdqEzMEftKytB8a7rknW82EASXB` where the address would be consistent with origin.

Comment: Honestly, just do not do this. The message that should be generated can be done with some JS ui, and you can convert between the ss58 and hex in that interface. It does not make sense to try and process ss58 addresses in the runtime.

Comment: Say I did it that way. Address would be converted to SS58 in JS, no problem there. Then user would go and sign a message (e.g. in MyCrypto) which they understand, because it would contain the address of their wallet, not some weird hex string (assuming they don't know how pubkey works). The signature then would be obviously different. You are saying there is no way how to verify, that the origin address specific to our network is equal to the SS58 address from such message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided against the address being processed in ss58 format in runtime as that it is regarded as strictly external thing. Moreover all functions related to ss58 in substrate use STD so it is not possible to use as-is for wasm compilation.

The alternative solution was to handle this situation in JS UI where I would explain to user what the pubkey address is and what ss58 address it maps to using [this](https://github.com/shawntabrizi/substrate-js-utilities/blob/master/utilities.js) code.
Address in signed message would stay in hex format.